# custom class init issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I've made my own custom class:

with this init method:

```
-(id)init:(NSString*) strFilename withImageData:(NSData*) objImageData withUploadTaskDelegate:(id<NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>) objUploadTaskDelegate
{
    filename = strFilename;
    uploadTaskDelegate = objUploadTaskDelegate;
    imageData = objImageData;
    return self;
}
```

I've made sure that the .h file also have the definition of this init file:

```
-(id)init:(NSString*) strFilename withImageData:(NSData*) objImageData withUploadTaskDelegate:(id<NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>) objUploadTaskDelegate;
```

however when I try to use it like this:

```
UploadQueueCellData *objTest =[UploadQueueCellData init:strImageName withImageData:objData withUploadTaskDelegate:objUploadDelegate];
```

it gives this error:

> No known class method for selector
>   'init:withImageData:withUploadTaskDelegate:'

this is my 3th day trying to develop in objective c code so I'm sure I'm missing something but I do not seem to be able to spot what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `init` method is an instance method, not the class method, check below example:

For instance method, you've to create an instance before using it.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

+ (void)aClassMethod;
- (void)anInstanceMethod;

@end
```

To call a method of MyClass, for instance method:

```
[[MyClass alloc] anInstanceMethod]
```

For Class method:

```
[MyClass aClassMethod]
```

In your case do this:

```
[[UploadQueueCellData alloc] init:strImageName withImageData:objData withUploadTaskDelegate:objUploadDelegate]
```

**Class Method**

A class method is applied to the class as a whole. If you check the alloc method, that's a class method denoted by the + before the method declaration. It's a class method because it is applied to the class to make a specific instance of that class.

**Instance Method**

You use an instance method to modify a specific instance of a class that is unique to that instance, rather than to the class as a whole. init for example (denoted with a - before the method declaration), is an instance method because you are normally modifying the properties of that class after it has been created with alloc.

Comment: what you showed me here I've tried to apply and it seems to be working :) Thank you so much I'm not sure I still understand why so I'll try and read more about class method vs instance method and what this alloc really means :) but thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Helbo Happy coding :-)